# Google Analytics: recording successful conversion from website ABC.com to XYZ.com

Tags: google-analytics

Our website `ABC.com` lists many events and each event listing has a registration button that links to an externally hosted form on `XYZ.com`. `XYZ.com` is controlled by a vendor. Each form (e.g. `xyz.com/event01.html`) does not have a separate thank you HTML, instead JavaScript is used to display a "Thank you" message within the same page.

What is the best approach to record a successful conversion from our website `ABC.com` through to `xyz.com/event01.html`?

I can not find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "controlled by a vendor" means you don't have access to the code on XYZ.com, then the best you can do is track the button clicks to XYZ.com as [outbound links](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) with [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).

As indicated [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en), outbound links are not automatically tracked by Google Analytics, so you'd need to manually tag them using JavaScript, which will then allow you see them as one of the event categories:

> Because links that lead away from your site are not automatically tracked by Google Analytics, you will need to manually tag all outbound links you want to track. To do this, you will add some custom JavaScript that uses the _*trackEvent* method to record these links and then modify the links you want to track.
>
> With this structure in place, you could then see Outbound Links as one of the event categories and drill down to see which particular outbound links are the most popular.

The steps for tracking button clicks as outbound links covered in the example [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) (edited for your needs) are:

1. Delay the outbound click by a fraction of a second (to provide the browser more time load the tracking code) by adding this JavaScript before your `</head>` tag:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action) { 

   try { 
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action]); 
   } catch(err){}

   setTimeout(function() {
   document.location.href = link;
   }, 100);
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Then you can log each button click by adding an `onClick` event to trigger the `trackOutboundLink` function above:

   ```
   <button onClick="trackOutboundLink('http://xyz.com/event01.html', 'Outbound Links', 
   'xyz.com'); return false;">Click me</button>
   ```

As specified there:

> The example above uses the category label Outbound Links. This is a
>   useful way to categorize all outbound links in the Event Tracking
>   reports. It sets the specific name of the website as the second
>   parameter in the call.

So change `xyz.com` above to whatever external site you want to attribute the button click to.

Comment: Yes "controlled by vendor" means that we do not have any control over the code. We already use event tracking to record the outbound link. Is there not any successful conversion code that we can use on an external site?

Comment: If you don't have access to the code on the external site, and the "Thank you" page doesn't return to your site either, then there's no way to use tracking code after the user leaves your site.

Comment: If we were to have access to the code on the external site and we could change the "Thank you" page to return to our site, what are the options?

Comment: You'd add your tracking code to the "Thank you" page on your site and then be able to view successful registrations by each form by viewing the [referral URLs](http://searchengineland.com/how-to-get-full-referral-content-urls-from-google-analytics-149549). Alternatively, if you can specify a different URL to the "Thank you" page for each form, then you can use [custom campaign parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en) as generated [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867) and view registrations by custom campaign.

Comment: Also, if you have the option of editing the JavaScript on their "Thank you" page, you might be able to add your tracking code there as well if you modify your tracking code to accommodate [cross-domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en), in which case you'd view the page totals for each form using a custom filter for their hostname and the form URI (see the bottom of that link).